# regex to match looping data in a file

Tags: regex

I have data in file in which records are like given below

```
X00
X01
NNN---Loop - 1
LLL
LLL      
LLL
 .
 .
 .
LLL (99th time)
NNN---Loop - 2
LLL
LLL
LLL
LLL
NNN---Loop - 3
LLL
T01
T00
```

And in data as you can see loops are there.

So it means

```
NNN--(can occur one time in one loop)
LLL--(Can occur 99 times in a loop)
```

And this loop should occur at least one time and Max limit is n times.

First two and last two records are going to be static.

So, I'm trying to match this data with regular expression. Tried google but not able to write this much complex regex for this loop type of data.

Any suggestion please ?

Thanks

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? It sounds like it would be straightforward to just process the file a line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You Tried the expression:

```
X01\nX02\n(N{3}(\nL{3}){1,99}\n){1,3}T01\nT02
```

Explanations:

- `X01\nX02\n` is for your beginning constant values.
- `(N{3}(\nL{3}){1,99}`if for your loop and inner values.
- Next `{1,3}` is the range of number of loops. I have used 3, you can changed it.
- `T01\nT02` for your last constant values.

You can justify the answer in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l5qAio/1)

Comment: thanks for your reply...but how can I give specific value in regex for first two records (X00, X01) and last two records (T01 and T00). Because that also needs to matched with regex for data in my file ?

Comment: @kelly, I have updated my answer. Check it now. Hope it helps you.

Comment: ....Thanks ..!! Could you please check this...https://regex101.com/r/X6vLUd/1  tried to edit some data and regex

Comment: are you sure about your data ? It is possible but your loop format isn't same !

Comment: Yes sunhuet...!! Its a final one...!! Did I make any mistake in regex mentioned in last comment ?

Comment: Hey, @kelly, I have edited your link and make a finalize of it.
Check : https://regex101.com/r/X6vLUd/2        Please, if that solve your problem then you can give an upvote.